# Find the number of days in a month in Java

Tags: java, datetime, calendar

How do you find the number of days in a month in Java?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Set the year and month on a Calendar object and then use [`getActualMaximum`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getActualMaximum%28int%29) to return the last day:

```
calendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
```

Answer (score 6):

Since Java 8, a simple way would be:

```
int daysInCurrentMonth = java.time.LocalDate.now().lengthOfMonth();
```

Answer (score 3):

## `java.time.Month`

Using the java.time classes, the [`java.time.Month`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Month.html) enum in particular.

```
int days = Month.FEBRUARY.minLength();  // 28
int days = Month.FEBRUARY.maxLength();  // 29
int days = Month.FEBRUARY.length( boolean_consider_leap_year ); // TRUE → 29, FALSE → 28.
```

You can get the `Month` object for a month number, 1-12 meaning January-December.

```
int monthNumber = Month.FEBRUARY.getValue();
```

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, `.Calendar`, & `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`.

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to java.time.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations.

Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) and further adapted to [Android](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system)) in [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) (see [*How to use…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706)).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as `Interval`, `YearWeek`, `YearQuarter`, and more.