# switch statemt functioning improperly and giving error when i put break;

Tags: java

The following is the code i used in a program -
**over here the month variable is an integer**

```
  switch(month) {
case 1:
case 3:
case 5:
case 7:
case 8:
case 10:
case 12:
  return 31;
  break;
case 2:
  return 28;
  break;
case 4:
case 6:
case 9:
case 11:
        return 30;
  break;
default:
  System.out.println("Invalid month.");
  return 0;
}
```

*surprisingly, when i use the above switch construct.. it gives an error saying.. code unreachable for statements after each break statement*

Then i removed all the break statements, and the new code looks like this ---

```
  switch(month) {
case 1:
case 3:
case 5:
case 7:
case 8:
case 10:
case 12:
  return 31;

case 2:
  return 28;

case 4:
case 6:
case 9:
case 11:
        return 30;

default:
  System.out.println("Invalid month.");
  return 0;
}
```

Now.. after removing the break statements .. the code worked perfectly well..

My question is... in the switch construct.. it is mandatory to use break.. or else the control flow will be continued.. and all the conditions are tested and executed!! right???

So why in the world is the previous  ** syntactically Right** version giving an error.. and the modified **syntactically incorrect** version running perfectly well..

Any explanation.. anyone!!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2545110/find-the-number-of-days-in-a-month-in-java

Comment: just so that there's no confusion, it is **not** syntactically incorrect to not use break statements in a switch, it is allowed, and should generally compile without error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because code stops executing when you use "return".

Comment: You only use "breaks" in order to prevent the rest of the "case"s from running. But since you "return", there is no way for anything else in the method to be run.

Comment: See this, it will help explain. They show cases where they don't use breaks and explain what happens: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html

Answer (score 1):

The error message is telling you that the `break` statements will never be executed, because they always follow a `return` statement.

It is not mandatory to use `break` statements in a `switch` construct.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the `break` because you already have `return`. If you `return` then you'll never reach the `break`, which is why you get the error.

Answer (score 0):

`return` exits the loop entirely, making `break` unreachable.

Answer (score 0):

break is not compulsary in the switch satatement. ic case you use a return statement it ill not be required.