# Get the number of days in the current month in Java

Tags: java, datetime

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Find the number of days in a month in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2545110/find-the-number-of-days-in-a-month-in-java)

I know these are some ways to do it, but I'm having hard time find information how to do it without passing specified date.

I just want to get number of days in a current month, how do I do that?

Comment: Why don't you want to pass in a date?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
int monthMaxDays = c.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
```